# Drawing multiple shapes depending on user Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to implement a menu based graph - wherein i will represent a vertex by a circle and each circle will have an index provided by the user.The user has to go to File menu and click on Addvertex to create a new node with an index.The Problem though is - The circle is drawn only once - any subsequent clicks to addVertex does not result in drawing of a circle -Can't understand Why...

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileChoose extends JFrame {

    public FileChoose() {
        JMenuBar l=new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file=new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem open=new JMenuItem("Addvertex");
        open.addActionListener(new Drawer());
        JMenuItem close=new JMenuItem("Exit");
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JMenu tools=new JMenu("Tools");
        file.add(open);
        file.add(close);

        this.setJMenuBar(l);
        l.add(tools);
        l.add(file);

        this.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    void HelloHere(String p) {
        Draw d = new Draw(p);
        this.add(d);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }

    class Drawer extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        Integer index;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel pn = new JPanel();
            JTextField jt = new JTextField(5);
            JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(5);
            pn.add(jt);
            pn.add(jt1);
            int result=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pn, "Enter the values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                index = Integer.parseInt(jt.getText());
                System.out.println(jt1.getText());
            }

            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setSize(500, 500);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            HelloHere(index.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        FileChoose f = new FileChoose();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Draw extends JPanel {

    String inp;

    public Draw(String gn) {
        inp = gn;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.nextInt(100);

        g2.drawOval(x, x * 2, 100, 100);
        g2.drawString(inp, x + (x / 2), x + (x / 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: please insert your code in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some pointers:

- Use [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for creation and manipulation of Swing Components.
- Dont extend `JFrame` class unnecessarily.
- Use [*anonymous* `Listener`s](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/events/anonymous_listener.html) where possible/allowed
- Make sure `JFrame#setVisible(..)` is the last call on `JFrame` instance specifically pointing here:

  ```
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setSize(500, 500);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      HelloHere(index.toString());
  ```
- Call `pack()` on `JFrame` instance rather than `setSize(..)`
- Do not use multiple `JFrame`s see: [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)
- The problem you are having is here:

  ```
  Draw d = new Draw(p);
  this.add(d);
  ```

  You are creating a new instance of `Draw` `JPanel` each time and then overwriting the last `JPanel` added with the new one (this is default the behavior of `BorderLayout`). To solve this read below 2 points:
- Call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on instance after adding components to show newly added components.
- Use an [appropriate `LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

As I am not sure of you expected results I have done as much fixing of the code as I could hope it helps:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileChoose {

    JFrame frame;

    public FileChoose() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar l = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Addvertex");

        open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            Integer index;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPanel pn = new JPanel();
                JTextField jt = new JTextField(5);
                JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(5);
                pn.add(jt);
                pn.add(jt1);
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pn, "Enter the values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    index = Integer.parseInt(jt.getText());
                    System.out.println(jt1.getText());
                }
                HelloHere(index.toString());
            }
        });

        JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JMenu tools = new JMenu("Tools");
        file.add(open);
        file.add(close);

        frame.setJMenuBar(l);
        l.add(tools);
        l.add(file);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void HelloHere(String p) {
        Draw d = new Draw(p);
        frame.add(d);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FileChoose f = new FileChoose();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Draw extends JPanel {

    String inp;

    public Draw(String gn) {
        inp = gn;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.nextInt(100);

        g2.drawOval(x, x * 2, 100, 100);
        g2.drawString(inp, x + (x / 2), x + (x / 2));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Declare this globally in your Draw class: `Random r=new Random();` as if you iniate a new Random instance each time you call `paintComponent()` the distributions will not be significant/random enough

Comment: Thanks for all the points you gave me...But,what repaint will do is - remove the existing circle drawn and then draw a new circle as specified by the user - what i want is - the already existing figure should continue to appear and the new circle appears somewhere else in a random location.(Hence the random value i used in my code)..Thanks

Comment: @404 You should than create an array of Ovals in your `Draw` class, and each tome a user adds a vertex an oval is added to the array, thus calling `repaint()` will cause all the ovals in the array to be drawn in `paintComponent()`

Comment: Each time i instantiate a new draw object -the array will be new- with no oval corresponding to it...

Comment: @404 well obviously than you wont initiate an new object for it each time, declare and create/initiate the Draw object globally and simply call you add oval method like so: `draw.addOval(int x,int y,int width, int height);`

Comment: Finally was able to do it - Nothing much - just decalred Draw object globally and called draw.paintcomponent() repeatedly - no need for an array - and no repaints too....Thanks a lot David..i appreciate your help throughout the course of the day..thanks

Comment: @404 its a pleasure. As for your comment *and called `draw.paintcomponent()` repeatedly ..* this is not the correct solution. You should call `repaint()` to honor *the `paint()` chain* hence the necessary array of objects to draw. What happens when the `JPanel` decides it needs to `repaint()` or is invoked to repaint through another top level container? all your shapes will be lost

Comment: @404 please see my updated post and this similar question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358658/paintcomponent-draws-other-components-on-top-of-my-drawing/13359279#13359279

Answer (score 2):

Every time the user creates a new node you create a new `JPanel` that is added to the `JFrame` of your application. In the absence of a specific layout it uses a `BorderLayout`. `BorderLayout` does not allow for more than one component to be added at each location. Your other calls to `add` are probably ignored.