# Java - Draw Square Around Circle

Tags: java, swing, graphics, resize, border

I have a program containing five buttons:

i) Square ii) Rectangle iii) Circle iv) Triangle v) Clear

Clicking on any of the first four buttons will draw the respective shape on the drawing canvas using the following code:

The shapes can be dragged.  They also should be resized.  I was just trying to change the cursor of the mouse around the four edges of the shape (NW, NE, SW, SE).  This works fine for squares and rectangles since they have four sides.  However, I have some problem implementing the same for the circle and triangle.

This is what I did in my mouseClicked event:

What I want to do is that if the string **shape_type** contains circle, for example, it draws a border around it so that the user can see the boundaries of the shape.

However, I can't just use the following code inside the if statement:

How can I draw the border please?  Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using `paint(..)` you should use a `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(..)`. Maybe see here for some usage of [`paintComponent(..)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358658/paintcomponent-draws-other-components-on-top-of-my-drawing/13359279#13359279). Also you will get better help sooner by posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: That's what the lecturer told us to do.  I am quite new to GUI programming.  In fact, this is my first Java GUI project.

Comment: Basically, every shape has its own class, each containing its paint method.  There is also a class called Shapes, and this is the place where the original paint method is.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the information nonetheless :)

Comment: Shape.getBounds() as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can't do painting in a `MouseListener` method.  What you can do is set `shapeUnderMouse` in your `mouseClicked` method, then call `repaint`.  You'll get better performance if you only repaint the areas that you know are changing visually, but it's not strictly necessary.

The `if (shapeUnderMouse != null)` block should be placed in your `paint` method.