# Image buffer for custom swing component?

Tags: java, image, swing, buffer

Should I implement `Image` as back buffer myself or there are already made components or options to activate back buffer?

My goal is to persist drawings on window move and hide/show...

**UPDATE**

I have tried to use JPanel so that I think it should work if it has a buffer, but failed:

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
                    g2d.drawOval(e.getX()-50, e.getY()-50, 100, 100);
                }
            });

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("JPanel Buffer Test");
            frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setBounds(100,100, 800, 600);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

Here circles are drawn on mouse clicks but disappear if window resize. So, no buffer apparently exist.

If component has buffer I would be able to draw something on it and it will persist on resize.

May be there is some way to access `JPanel`'s buffer, other that `getGraphics`?

**UPDATE 2**

Below is how I did buffer manually. My question is isn't it done in the library already.
Example resamples buffer on resize which is not mandatory.

```
    private BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if( bufferedImage != null ) {
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

@Override
public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    if( bufferedImage == null ) {
        bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }
    else {
        if( bufferedImage.getWidth() != width || bufferedImage.getHeight() != height ) {
            BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.scale((double)width/bufferedImage.getWidth(), (double)height/bufferedImage.getHeight());

            AffineTransformOp scaleOp = 
                   new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

            bufferedImage = scaleOp.filter(bufferedImage, scaledImage);
        }
    }
    super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
}


public Graphics2D createImageGraphics() {
    if( bufferedImage != null ) {
        return bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a `JPanel`, which by default is automatically is *double buffered* (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html) for more), you can than simply override `paintComponent(..)` and do all drawing there and than add the `JPanel` to a container like `JFrame`.

Have a look here for more:

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

You might also want to fully control the repainting cycle of your `JPanel`, this can be done by calling `setIgnoreRepaint(true)`.

Alternatively you may want to look at [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) (which will allow you some advanced functions but for all intensive purposes `JPanel` with overriden `paintComponent` and automatic *double buffering* and `setIgnoreRepaint(true)` is equivalent), this is usually implemented with a `Canvas` like so:

```
BufferStrategy myStrategy;

while (!done) {
    Graphics g = myStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
    render(g);//draw the frame/graphics
    g.dispose();
    myStrategy.show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what for should I override `paintComponent` if `JPanel` has buffer as you said? `paintComponent` is called each time component requires to redraw, so this is for case visual information is to be regenerated each time.

Comment: @SuzanCioc the only way I know of doing that is by creating an array list which holds each oval you draw, in paintComponent you will than iterate through the array. And redraw ovals.

Comment: @SuzanCioc the only way I know of doing that is by creating an array list which holds each oval you draw, in paintComponent you will than iterate through the array. And redraw ovals. Here is a similar answer which will help, it however draws rectangles: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13359279/1133011