# Strange JFrame Behavior

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I have the following program which has some very strange and unwanted behavior when it runs. Its supposed to have two buttons, "Start" and "Stop, but when I click "Start" another button shows up right below "Start". Here's a print screen of what I'm talking about:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this ugly problem?

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class TwoButtonsTest {

    JFrame frame;
    Timer timer;
    boolean isClicked;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TwoButtonsTest test = new TwoButtonsTest();
    test.go();
    }

    public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    startButton.addActionListener(new StartListener());
    JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new StopListener());

    final DrawPanel myDraw = new DrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, myDraw);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, startButton);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, stopButton);


    frame.setVisible(true);

    timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            myDraw.repaint();
        }
        });
    }

    class StartListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //needs to be implemented
        if(!isClicked) {
        }
        isClicked = true;
        timer.start();
    }
    }

    class StopListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //needs to be implemented
        timer.stop();
        isClicked = false;
    }
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int red = (int)(Math.random()*256);
        int blue = (int)(Math.random()*256);
        int green = (int)(Math.random()*256);

        g.setColor(new Color(red, blue, green));

        Random rand = new Random();
        // following 4 lines make sure the rect stays within the frame
        int ht = rand.nextInt(getHeight());
        int wd = rand.nextInt(getWidth());

        int x = rand.nextInt(getWidth()-wd);
        int y = rand.nextInt(getHeight()-ht);

        g.fillRect(x,y,wd,ht);
    }
    } // close inner class
}
```

Also I'm trying to get the Start button to do two things. One is to of course start the animation but when the Stop button is pressed and I press Start again, I want it to clean the screen so to speak and start the animation again a new. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not call `super.paintComponent(Graphics g)` in overriden `paintComponent(..)` method which you should in order to honor the *paint chain* and thus the painting of other components.

This call should also be the first call within the method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);

    //do painting here
}
```

A probem might arise that drawings are not persistent. You must than have a way to store drawings and redraw every time. The most common is an `ArrayList` which will hold objects to be drawn (thus you cann add to the list remove etc), you would than iterate over the list and redraw each object in `paintComponent`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358658/paintcomponent-draws-other-components-on-top-of-my-drawing/13359279#13359279) for an example.

- Also please remember to create and manipulate Swing components on [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) :

  ```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           //create UI and components here
      }
  });
  ```
- Dont call `setSize(..)` on `JFrame` rather override `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` and return an appropriate height which fits all components, than call `JFrame#pack()` before setting `JFrame` visible (but after adding all components).
- No need for `getContentPane().add(..)` as of Java 6+ `add(..)` defaults to *contentPane*
- Do not re declare `Random` i.e `Random r=new Random()` each time `paintComponent` is called as this will make the distributions of the values less *random* rather initiate it once when class is created and call methods on the instance

Here is the fixed code (with above fixes implemented):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoButtonsTest {

    JFrame frame;
    Timer timer;
    boolean isClicked;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TwoButtonsTest test = new TwoButtonsTest();
                test.go();
            }
        });
    }
    final DrawPanel myDraw = new DrawPanel();

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new StartListener());
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new StopListener());


        frame.add(myDraw, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(stopButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                myDraw.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    class StartListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //needs to be implemented
            if (!isClicked) {
            }

            myDraw.clearRects();

            isClicked = true;
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    class StopListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //needs to be implemented
            timer.stop();
            isClicked = false;
        }
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        private ArrayList<MyRectangle> rects = new ArrayList<>();
        private Random rand = new Random();

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            addRect();
            for (MyRectangle r : rects) {
                g.setColor(r.getColor());
                g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        public void clearRects() {
            rects.clear();
        }

        public void addRect() {
            // following 4 lines make sure the rect stays within the frame
            int ht = rand.nextInt(getHeight());
            int wd = rand.nextInt(getWidth());

            int x = rand.nextInt(getWidth() - wd);
            int y = rand.nextInt(getHeight() - ht);

            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

            rects.add(new MyRectangle(x, y, wd, ht, new Color(red, blue, green)));
        }
    } // close inner class
}

class MyRectangle extends Rectangle {

    Color color;

    public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color c) {
        super(x, y, w, h);
        this.color = c;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do super.paintComponent(g), wouldn't that refresh the screen every single time paintComponent is called? Which is not something I want to do. Or am I wrong in my understanding of it?

Comment: @nickecarlo of course you want the screen to be redrawn, and you can see what happens if you dont call it. The only problem that might occur is your drawing will be erased which can be fixed by making them persist, ie adding all Rectangles to be drawn to an ArrayList and iterate over the array on `paintComponent` thus they will be redrawn each time the screen is

Comment: thanks for the advice. I have upvoted your answer as well. I will try both the answers out and accept the one that works the best.

Comment: Okay, I am accepting your answer since it explained the reasons behind the how and why and also corrected my bad practices. Now I just need to implement clearing the rectangles when I click start after clicking stop and I should be good to go. I am sure I will be back here if I can't figure that out. Thanks a lot David.

Comment: Alright, I can't for the life of me figure out how to clear it all up. I have written a method in the DrawPanel class and have passed the ArrayList reference for it to do rects.clear(); but I can't get it implemented at all. If I just add rects.clear() in the paintComponent method, it clears it fine. But I want to be able to clear it when I click the start button after clicking the stop button. I am pretty new at swing and buttons so maybe I am missing something that's very clear.

Comment: @nickecarlo create a public method called clearRects in your JPanel class, than when stop is pressed/start is pressed call the method using the JPanel instance to clear the list

Comment: thanks, I created the method and everything but the only thing I was doing wrong was instantiating DrawPanel class's myDraw object inside of the go() method. And so I had to instantiate DrawPanel again with Stop and that created a whole new object and AHH. Thanks for your patience with me really, I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake and didn't notice it.

Answer (score 3):

I wish I could offer a solution, but as of yet I haven't found one. I can tell you the root of the "problem" here lies in the way you are drawing the Center section of your BorderLayout. You are overriding the whole paintComponent() function for this program and having whatever it creates put into the Center of your BoarderLayout. In this case, each time you click a button, the program calls the repaint to draw the image of a clicked button, but since you have also added ANY of the drawn objects to the Center panel, it also is drawn there. Since this specific repaint doesn't specify a location, it goes in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your button problem on my Windows XP computer by invoking SwingUtilities.

I formatted your Java code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TwoButtonsTest implements Runnable {

    JFrame frame;
    Timer timer;
    boolean isClicked;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TwoButtonsTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new StartListener());
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new StopListener());

        final DrawPanel myDraw = new DrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, myDraw);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, startButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, stopButton);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                myDraw.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    class StartListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // needs to be implemented
            if (!isClicked) {
            }
            isClicked = true;
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    class StopListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // needs to be implemented
            timer.stop();
            isClicked = false;
        }
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

            g.setColor(new Color(red, blue, green));

            Random rand = new Random();
            // following 4 lines make sure the rect stays within the frame
            int ht = rand.nextInt(getHeight());
            int wd = rand.nextInt(getWidth());

            int x = rand.nextInt(getWidth() - wd);
            int y = rand.nextInt(getHeight() - ht);

            g.fillRect(x, y, wd, ht);
        }
    } // close inner class
}
```

To clean the screen when you press the Start button, you're going to have to add some methods to your DrawPanel class.

Here's one way to do it.

```
class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        protected boolean eraseCanvas;

        public void setEraseCanvas(boolean eraseCanvas) {
            this.eraseCanvas = eraseCanvas;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (eraseCanvas) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(0,  0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            } else {
                int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
                int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
                int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

                g.setColor(new Color(red, blue, green));

                Random rand = new Random();
                // following 4 lines make sure the rect stays within the frame
                int ht = rand.nextInt(getHeight());
                int wd = rand.nextInt(getWidth());

                int x = rand.nextInt(getWidth() - wd);
                int y = rand.nextInt(getHeight() - ht);

                g.fillRect(x, y, wd, ht);
            }
        }
    } // close inner class
```

Comment: -1 I would not consider this the correct. It seems by chance using `SwingUtilities` actually even makes a difference, as even when invoked on `EDT` if `super.paintComponent` is not called this anomaly could still occur.

Comment: @David Kroukamp: super.paintComponent is not required unless the extended JPanel class has JComponent children.  Since the OP is using the extended JPanel class as a canvas, the super call is not required.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc with my code in my answer removing call to `super.paintComponent` causes the same anomaly as OPs image in post, so I stand by my -1 sorry.

Comment: @David Kroukamp: The super call causes the JPanel to be painted white before drawing the random rectangle.  Removing the super call causes the random rectangles to be painted over each other.  All the super call does is invoke the JPanel paintComponent method, which paints the background of the JPanel white.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc see MatthewFredericks answer it says it all. and no need to reinvent clearing the screen when `super.paintComponent` will do that for us