# Java how to paint rectangles on mouseclick

Tags: java, swing, drawrect, graphics2d

As the title says, I'm having a hard time trying to draw some rectangles (filled) in JApplet.
The exact goal is to have a 50x50 table and when you click on a targeted cell, to make it filled (possibly done by drawing a filled rectangle). I have done the maths about the coordinates of the starting point, but for some reason I can't draw the new rectangle in the MouseClicked method. Any suggestions?

```
public class Main extends JApplet {

public static final int DIMX = 800;
public static final int DIMY = 800;
public static final int ratio = 16;
Graphics g;
boolean drawing;
public int cX;
public int cY;

public Main() {
    JPanel MainFrame = new JPanel();
    MainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 800));
    MainFrame.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    JPanel Table = new JPanel();
    Table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    Table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    add(MainFrame, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(Table, BorderLayout.WEST);
    addMouseListener(new clicked());
}



public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 800; i += 16) {
        g.drawLine(0, i, 800, i);
        g.drawLine(i, 0, i, 800);
//            g.fillRect(cX, cY, 16, 16);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame win = new JFrame("Retarded Bullshit");
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    win.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1216, 840));
    win.setContentPane(new Main());
    win.pack();
    win.setVisible(true);

}

public class clicked extends JApplet implements MouseListener {

public int cX;
public int cY;
Graphics g;

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
//            Point a = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    int cellX = e.getX();
    int cellY = e.getY();
    if (cellX < 800 && cellX > 0 && cellY < 800 && cellY > 0) {
        cX = cellX / 16 + 1;
        cY = cellY / 16 + 1;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "" + cX + " " + cY);
    }
```

Comment: Also consider a `GridLayout` of `ColorLabel`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5137250/230513).

Comment: "I can't draw the new rectangle in the MouseClicked method". Can you clarify "can't"?  It is crashing, just not showing up, or something else.  The details of how something is not working are useful to figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Also consider `JTable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a relatively simple concept (no offense).

To start with, don't mix your code with `JApplet` and `JFrame`.  If you want to use your application in these two mediums, separate the logic into a separate component (like `JPanel`) which you can easily add to either.  You really shouldn't add a top level container to another top level container (adding an applet to a frame) - it's messy.

Avoid overriding the `paint` methods of top level containers (like `JApplet`), instead, use a custom component (like `JPanel`) instead and override it's `paintComponent` method.

In your example, you should be calling `super.paint` rather then `super.paintComponents`.  `paint` does important work, you don't want to skip it - but you should be using `JComponent#paintComponent`

`MouseListener`s should added to the components that you are interested in managing mouse events.  Because `clicked` is never added to any containers, it will never recieve mouse events.

Take a look at

- [How to write mouse listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) (because every Swing developer should have an understanding of this)

[image]

```
public class SimplePaint03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimplePaint03();
    }

    public SimplePaint03() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new PaintPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Shape> grid;
        private List<Shape> fill;

        public PaintPane() {
            grid = new ArrayList<>(5);
            fill = new ArrayList<>(5);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    for (Shape shape : grid) {
                        if (shape.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                            if (fill.contains(shape)) {
                                fill.remove(shape);
                            } else {
                                fill.add(shape);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            int colWidth = 200 / 50;
            int rowHeight = 200 / 50;

            for (int row = 0; row < 50; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
                    grid.add(new Rectangle(colWidth * col, rowHeight * row, colWidth, rowHeight));
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Shape cell : fill) {
                g2d.fill(cell);
            }
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (Shape cell : grid) {
                g2d.draw(cell);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Additional**

Information from one paint cycle to another is not maintained.  You are required to repaint the component exactly the way you want it to appear.  This means you will need to maintain a list of click points that can be repainted at any time.

Comment: +1 for advice especially not mixing `JApplet` and `JFrame`. @user2049066 See also [this variation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358658/paintcomponent-draws-other-components-on-top-of-my-drawing/13359279#13359279). Also notice the `EventQueue`/`SwingUtilitites` blocks in `main(string[] args)` (used in both MadProgrammmers and the linked answer) dont forget to create and manipulate Swing components in EDT same applies for `JApplet` except `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` is used in overriden `init()`

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel or JComponent(). Then you add the panel to the JApplet.

If you only want to paint certain squares then you are going to need a List to keep track of which cells to paint. Then every time you repaint the component you will need to loop through the List and paint the cells.

Your MouseListener would not extend JApplet. When you click on a cell you would update the List from above to indicate that the cell needs to be painted. Then you would invoke repaint() on the panel so that your painting code will be invoked.

You may also want to look at [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) which gives two different ways to do this type of painting depending on your exact requirement.